# How do you replace arbitrary characters with a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, methods, syntax, charat

I'm trying to create a method that replaces an individual character in a string with another string so far, these are my parameters.

public static String replaceAt(String str, int position, String replacement)

It's supposed to look something like this when it runs correctly:

```
method         input                          output

replaceAt     "Hello, World", 5, " comma"     Hello comma World
```

This is what I have so far.

```
{
   String result = "";

  char character = str.charAt(position);

  str = str.replace(character, replacement);

  result = str;

  return result;
 }
```

but I'm pretty sure I'm messing up the syntax somehow, any pointers on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), then you could instantiate one with your input `str` and then call [`StringBuilder#replace(int, int, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace-int-int-java.lang.String-) like

```
public static String replaceAt(String str, int position, String replacement) {
    return new StringBuilder(str).replace(position, position + 1, 
            replacement).toString();
}
```

If you can't use that, then you might use [`String#substring(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) and concatenate your output like

```
return str.substring(0, position) + replacement + str.substring(position + 1);
```

**Note** that internally uses `StringBuilder` to perform the concatenation (at least in recent Java releases), so it is equivalent to

```
return new StringBuilder(str.substring(0, position)).append(replacement)
        .append(str.substring(position + 1)).toString();
```

(in very old releases `StringBuffer` was used).

Comment: Thanks, it worked for the first two tests I ran using arguments              
"Hello, World", 5, " comma" and "Mary", 3, "ie". But when I tried         
"Mary", 4, "ie" I got Maryie instead of Marie.

Comment: The second code you mentioned returned an java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
 at Strings.replaceAt(Strings.java:15) error when i ran it with "Mary", 4, "ie"

Comment: @Rod112 `"Mary"` doesn't have a character at position 4 that can be replaced.  It's not clear why you would expect this to work.  If your requirement is that 4 should be treated the same as 3, you'll have to make this a special case.

Comment: @ajb You're right, I looked at it closely and thought It may have been a mistake on my part, but it might be something wrong with the software I'm using to run several tests.

Comment: I'm not sure how to account for special cases, that's not something we've covered just yet.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem with using `replace`, or other solutions that search for regexes, is that we don't know whether the character at that position is the only one in the string.  Suppose the input string is `"Hello, world, good morning"`.  Then your `replaceAt` would return `"Hello comma world comma good morning"`.  Maybe that's what you really want (it isn't clear), but a method that pretends to be one that "replaces" the character "at" the given "position" with a string, shouldn't do more than that.  (If that's really what you want, I recommend changing the name and the parameters.)

Assuming you want to replace the character at that position, and *only* the character at that position, I'd recommend using `substring` instead:

```
public static String replaceAt(String str, int position, String replacement) {
    return str.substring(0, position) + replacement + str.substring(position + 1);
}
```

**Edit:** If you want to handle the case where `position` == the string length, so that there is no character at that position:

```
public static String replaceAt(String str, int position, String replacement) {
    return str.substring(0, position) + replacement + (position == str.length() ? "" : str.substring(position + 1));
}
```

(If `position` > the string length, the first `substring` won't work.  Depending on the use case, you can let it throw an exception if this case isn't supposed to happen.  Or you could do this:)

```
public static String replaceAt(String str, int position, String replacement) {
    return str.substring(0, Math.min(position, str.length())) + replacement + (position >= str.length() ? "" : str.substring(position + 1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well with the first two tests I ran. But i ran into an java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
 at Strings.replaceAt(Strings.java:15)
 at StringsCodeCheck.main(StringsCodeCheck.java:52) error when I tried running it with "Mary", 4, "ie" as my input

Comment: Please see my earlier comment.  The purpose of the method would be to replace the character at position 4.  But there's no character at position 4, so why would you expect it to work?

Comment: would an if statement work, one that returns the string as it is if the character of the position is nothing?

Comment: Yes, but a ternary operator would also work.  See my edit.